# Is Orchard Project (orchardcms) mature enough for a medium-size project for company offering financial services?

Tags: orchardcms

At the time of writing Orchard project (http://www.orchardproject.net/) is in version 1.1.
I am considering that for a financial services' web site. Stability, security is of high priority here. Mostly that would be used to serve standard 'about-us' info plus various registration forms, sales' campaigns (landing pages/tracking user). It is important to be multi-culture friendly.

Comment: The question as it stands is subjective. I suggest you rephrase it along the lines of 'Does Orchard support feature x that I require?' in order to get a decent answer.  It's up to you to evaluate whether a technology is suitable for your project.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Orchard in two medium-sized commercial projects and it works very well. It is perfectly stable.

What do you mean by "security"?

- From the server perspective it's an ordinary ASP.NET application, so all security-related stuff is the same as for those written from scratch.
- From the CMS perspective though, Orchard has a user/roles authorization mechanism built-in.
  User authentication leverages the ASP.NET Forms Authentication.

Multi-culture content is supported. There is also a [Culture Picker](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.CulturePicker) module, that allows to switch the culture of the whole site on the visitor's end.