# Orchard CMS Ready for Prime Time

Tags: orchardcms

We want to build a product for the market and have other products in WordPress.  We are more of a Microsoft shop so we have been watching Orchard for a little bit.

The question is do you think Orchard CMS is ready for prime time?  Would you release a commercial product on top of it as a framework or just build your own?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975093/is-orchard-project-orchardcms-mature-enough-for-a-medium-size-project-for-compa) (although touching security and stability of Orchard).*

As I said there, I found Orchard perfectly good for building a commercial applications on top of it. Basically I use it to build application front-ends (leveraging the flexible Orchard content type mechanism) which communicate with underlying BI services. It works like a charm and saved me a lot of time.

Would I release a boxed product using Orchard? I guess so, as reinventing the wheel is not the thing I like to do and also because Orchard is a giant time-saver (which greatly shortens TTM). As v1.0 was not commercial-ready IMO, v1.1 and newer surely are.